# How do I raise a SILENT fatal exception delphi

Tags: delphi, exception

Situation:
I have a list that is growing on hard drive and I want to load it in memory for processing. At some point, I will get EOutofMemory. What I need is a way to test the code that is in my except block:

```
implementation
uses sysutils;
function loadit(var F:File);
begin
   Try
   {load list code}
   except
   on EOutofMemory do
      begin
      {error handling code to be tested}
      end;
   end; // the try block
end;
```

What I need is a call to the exception block WITHOUT actually waiting for the out of memory condition to be met. I have looked at raise, and I've not found anything that would allow to raise an exception the way I need it.

```
raise EOutofMemory;
```

does not compile.

```
raise;
```

compiles but raises what?

```
raise EOutofMemory.NewInstance;
```

compiles, but I wonder what it does with the object after? Will it be destroyed at the moment I leave the error handling block, stay behind in the heap or whatever the compiler decides to do with it?

Assert does not allow to specify anything; anyway it's not its goal.

Answer (score 8):

Since you won't have enough memory to create an exception when you're out of memory, memory for `EOutOfMemory` is pre-allocated at startup. You use that instead of creating a new one. As the [`documentation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EOutOfMemory) states:

> Never raise EOutOfMemory directly. Instead, call the global
>   [OutOfMemoryError](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.OutOfMemoryError) procedure.

```
   Try
      OutOfMemoryError;
   except
   on EOutofMemory do
      begin
      {error handling code to be tested}
      end;
   end; // the try block
```

Answer (score 1):

The raise operator generates an exception.
The exception is an object describes a wrong situation.
If you want to raise an exception you should prepare it. At least you should fill up an error message.

```
var
  E: Exception;
begin
  E := Exception.Create('Error message');
  raise E;
end;
```

You should use Create instead of NewInstance.

EOutOfMemory is a class. It's not possible to raise a class, but a class instance. You could create instance of EOutOfMemory.

```
raise EOutOfMemory.Create;
```

But it's not possible as Sertac Akyuz wrote.

The empty **raise** operator re-raises already caught exception instance without any changes. Have a look:

```
try
except
  on E: EOutOfMemory do
  begin
    E.Message := 'Oops!';
    raise E;
  end;
  on EOSException do
    raise;
end;
```